# DevExpress ASPxSplitter reload just the right side

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, navbar, splitterpanel

I have in my MasterPage an ASPxSplitter with two panes :

```
   <dx:ASPxSplitter ID="ASPxSplitter1" runat="server" FullscreenMode="True" Height="100%" Theme="BlackGlass" Width="100%">

        <panes>
            <dx:SplitterPane Size="20%" Name="leftPane">
                <contentcollection>

                    <dx:SplitterContentControl runat="server"  SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">

                        <dx:ASPxNavBar ID="ASPxNavBar1" runat="server" AllowSelectItem="True" Width="100%">
                            <ClientSideEvents ItemClick="OnItemClicked" />
                            <Groups>
                                <dx:NavBarGroup Text="Entreprises extérieures">
                                    <Items>
                                        <dx:NavBarItem Text="Entreprise extérieure" NavigateUrl="~/EntrepriseExternes.aspx">
                                        </dx:NavBarItem>
                                        <dx:NavBarItem Text="Intervenant" NavigateUrl="~/Intervenants.aspx">
                                        </dx:NavBarItem>

                                    </Items>
                                </dx:NavBarGroup>
                            </Groups>
                        </dx:ASPxNavBar>
                    </dx:SplitterContentControl>
                </contentcollection>
            </dx:SplitterPane>
            <dx:SplitterPane>
                <ContentCollection>
                        <dx:SplitterContentControl ID="RightPane" runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </dx:SplitterContentControl>
                </ContentCollection>
            </dx:SplitterPane>
        </panes>
    </dx:ASPxSplitter>
```

When a NavBarItem is clicked I want to reload just the right side is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use AspxCallbackPanel inside you right panel. On click event of navbar perform callback for that panel. During callback do anything you want.

If right panel content variants aren't very big - you can load them all and just use SetVisible() on client side on navbar click.

Or even any other solution that highly depends on your task details